# I want to send notification in banner to users How to do that?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]I had implemented firebase push notification in react native iOS app. But now I want to send notification in banner to users How to do like that?

Comment: you can do it from your firebase profile

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I had edited my question.

Comment: admob and push notifications is not the same, if you need advertise banner you must set settings in admob cabinet

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik Can I send custom ad banner to users? If yes, is there any example of integration and all?

Comment: look through delegate methods

Comment: Are you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can show a modal with the content of notification:

```
   this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications()
  .onNotification(notification => {
    // this.displayNotification(notification);
    this.setState({notification:notification})
  });
```

...

Comment: how can I get notification content in model?